# Laravel DatabaseTransactions for PHPunit have no effect

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Writing tests for an existing API, there are many cases where the database has been modified. What I have been doing is something as follows:

```
public function testPut()
{
    //setup 
    /*Copy an existing record and take its data as an array.
    * the function being tested will take an array of data 
    * and create a new record. Using existing data guarantees
    * the data is valid.
    */

    $customerObj = Customer::getInstance(); //regular instantiation disabled in this api 
    $cust = ArCust::first()->toArray();
    $oldNum = $cust['CUST_NO'];
    unset($cust['CUST_NO']);
    $custNo = rand(1, 9999999999999);


    //test
    /*put() creates a new customer record in the database 
      and returns the object.
    */

    $this->assertInternalType('object', $customerObj->put($custNo, $cust));


    //cleanup
    /*manually remove the newly created record.
    */
    ArCust::whereNam($cust['NAM'])->whereNotIn('CUST_NO', [$oldNum])->delete();
}
```

I am now running into instances where the API creates or updates many tables based on foreign keys. It would take far too much time to go through and manually reset each table.

The `DatabaseTransaction` trait provided by Laravel is supposed to take care of resetting everything for you. However, when I use it, I still find the test-created records in the database. 
Here is how I have used it:

```
class CustomerTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function testPut()
    {
        //setup
        $customerObj = Customer::getInstance();
        $cust = ArCust::first()->toArray();
        $oldNum = $cust['CUST_NO'];
        unset($cust['CUST_NO']);
        $custNo = rand(1, 9999999999999);


        //test
        $this->assertInternalType('object', $customerObj->put($custNo, $cust));

    }
}
```

Am I using this incorrectly? Getting `DatabaseTransactions` to work correctly will save an incredible amount of time, as well as make the testes more readable to other people.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that we had multiple database connections defined in config > database.

In the `database.php` conf file, I changed the default connection to the correct database using its name as defined in the setup:

```
$connection = 'counterpoint';
```

and `DatabaseTransactions` now works.

This next step to this solution is to direct the connection of each test to the appropriate database rather than change the global connection.

Comment: Regarding your next step, you can define which connections should be used by the Trait by declaring a class property `connectionsToTransact` with an array containing the name of the connections.